# Custom delegate method is triggered ok, but values not persist within the other methods

Tags: objective-c, ios5, delegates, persistence, modalviewcontroller

i'm new at objective-c. I'm doing an app with modal view, that passes data to his parent view. I implemented a protocol delegate, and the data is passed ok, but it not persist within the others methods, because when i try to do something with the value passed seems to be null outside my delegate method. I do a NSLog inside delegate method and the value is there, but when i want to use the value in another method seems to be missed. I'm not using ARC.

My Main ViewController.h:

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate
- (void)didReceiveWeight:(NSString *)weight andUnit:(NSString *) unit;
@end

@interface LogWeightTableViewController : UITableViewController<ModalViewDelegate> {
NSNumber *weightPassed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *WeightSelected;
//...
```

My Main ViewController.m:

```
//...this method is triggered ok, and _weightPassed has the value.
- (void)didReceiveWeight:(NSString *)weight andUnit:(NSString *)unit{

NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
_weightPassed = [f numberFromString:weight]; //_weightPassed have null in another methods
[f release];

NSString *value = [[[NSString stringWithString:weight] stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:unit];

[WeightSelected setText:valor];
}
```

My ModalView.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ModalViewDelegate> delegate;
```

My ModalView.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//...
LogWeightTableViewController *logWeightTVC = [[LogWeightTableViewController alloc]init];
self.delegate = logWeightTVC;

//...when i press a button to go back to main view call the delegate method:
[delegate didReceiveWeight:valor andUnit:unidad];
```

Going back to my MainViewController.m y want to do something with my _weightPassed:

```
- (IBAction)saveLogToDataBase:(id)sender {
// ... do some stuff
[row setKg: _weightPassed]; //<-- here _weightPassed is null
```

I think i'm missing some important concept or something, hope someone can help me with this

Comment: So now you use _datePassed or _weightPassed?

Comment: I'm sorry, i edited the code now, it's _weightPassed.

Comment: Maybe use `_weightPassed = [[f numberFromString:weight] retain]`?

Comment: I tried with `_weightPassed = [[f numberFromString:weight] retain]` but still the same result

Comment: Ah, I see now! You're recreating the logWeightTvc every time the delegate method is fired... That's not good, you need to change your design pattern a bit.

Comment: Thanks, i'm doing it now in the prepareForSegue method:  `      - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"modalSegue"])
    {
        ModalView *pickerView = [segue destinationViewController];
        pickerView.delegate = self;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

As H2CO3 recommended, I've changed my design pattern and now the delegate is passed before the modal view is showed. I done it in the prepareForSegue method:

```
 - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"modalSegue"]) {
        ModalView *pickerView = [segue destinationViewController]; 
        pickerView.delegate = self; 
    }
}
```